# Using schema contained in a json file for spark.read() in Python

Tags: python, json, pyspark, schema

Questions:

1. Is my schema conversion to json correct?
2. How do I pass json file to provide schema for spark.read()

I have the following schema hardcoded into the python script and this works perfectly for my code:

```
schema1 = StructType([
            StructField("computer_name", StringType()),
            StructField("owner_id", StringType())])
```

And I want to move the schema out of the script in a json file so i made the following conversion:

```
{"StructType":[
    {"fields":[
    {"metadata":{},"name":"computer_name","nullable":true,"type":"string"},
    {"metadata":{},"name":"owner_id","nullable":true,"type":"string"},
    "type":"struct"}
    ]
}
```

I want to read a file and provide my own schema using the json file:

```
df=spark.read.option("header", "true").schema(schema_json_file).load(file_names)
```

This will throw the following error:

```
ERROR: schema should be StructType or string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to solve the issue:

**json file:**

```
{"fields":[
{"metadata":{},"name":"computer_name","nullable":true,"type":"string"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"owner_id","nullable":true,"type":"string"}],
"type":"struct"}
```

**Python code:**

```
schema_file = s3.Object("bucket_name",  "prefix")
schema_file = json.loads(schema_file.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
custom_schema = StructType.fromJson(schema_file)
df=spark.read.option("header", "true").schema(custom_schema).load(file_names)
```

In my case, the json file with the schema is located in an S3 location.